# Dynamic news showcase on homepage and impact on SEO and indexing

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, search-results, homepage

I want to highlight the latest news of the week or month on the homepage of my website. On another page of my site, I have a complete and comprehensive list of the news that would duplicate what is on the homepage.  So the news on homepage would be variable. In fact, I would have to remove each item after one month.

Even if I have the same news URL links in another page, removing the URL links from homepage would affect heavily for Google indexing? Is there a possibility that I could lose position in the SERPs?

This would practically make my site into a daily newspaper site!

Comment: I think that would depend on how much of the home page was dedicated to these news links. Are they sidebar links? Or do they take up the whole page? As well, how often do they change or are updated?

Comment: I see your new edit that sorta answers the question.

Comment: the news varies not daily but at least montly! In the homepage there are also the navigation links in the side, the information about company name in the footer, and some other internal links! Practically the news take the whole page!

Comment: the same matter you can see here in the stackexchange homepage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. No worries mate! What? You want a longer answer?

The home page will rank what it will rank. (Don't freak out yet.) However, how it will appear in the SERPs I think is the real question.

For sites that are structured as you describe, most search users do not necessarily come to the home page during a search. The articles are going to appear in the SERPs for any query simply because of keyword match, though it is possible that the home page will periodically out perform the article page. A home page that changes, will perform well- do not worry about that, but rarely will match the users search as compared to the articles.

Now for the good news. The more people who visit your articles and link to your articles, the better your site will perform overall and the more valuable the home page becomes. In your case, returning visitors will want to come to your home page to scan articles. So in the end, if not for search, the home page should do rather well for direct visitors. And that is the other side of the coin. A rather important one too!